ZigBee SDK and Telink IoT Studio 2024.8 how to add new project
TelinkIoTStudio_UserGuide_en.pdf does not say anything how to create new project.
ZigBee SDK Developer Manual (Section 2.1.4 Add new project  page 20) explains how to add new project.
But in reality following this manual new project is not creating, and just creating additional build configuration for selected example sources.
In other words, Telink ZigBee SDK having predefined directory structure, and in "/apps" directory located examples applications and should be placed user defined applications.
My problem is, when i try to create and add my new project as described in Telink ZigBee SDK  Manual (page 20), in reality, new separate project is not creating, instead of it, just creating additional build configuration for selected predefined example.
I tried to create manually, let say, "/apps/myApp" directory, and just for tests, copied to it some application, then modified all available options of newly created build configuration, but still directory "apps/myApp" showing by Telink IDE as greyed, and, let say "/apps/exampleSDK" as active.
The question is how to create absolutely separate project which is NOT depend on initial example project.
Telink IoT Studio 2024.8 is eclipse based IDE and the last resort can be to modify manually .project and .cproject files, but i really dont like the idea.

The guidence how to create absolutely separate project which is NOT depend on initial example project i found in Telink BLE SDK for old version Telink IDE.
The document Guide For Adding New Project On Existing SDK describing exact steps to add new project.
But BLE SDK directory structure differ from ZigBee SDK, so instead of directory "/vendor" should read as "/apps".
And other small differences:

Menus of old Telink IDE slightly differ from Telink IoT Studio 2024, but the principle is the same.

Compiling parameters in document refer to BLE, so should be used values as in ZigBee examples build configurations.

Before performing step 7. Configure Compiling Exclusions (page 20) should exit IDE, and add to /tl_zigbee_sdk/build/tlsr_tc32/.project file
 <link>
     <name>apps/myApp</name>
     <type>2</type>
     <locationURI>PARENT-2-PROJECT_LOC/apps/myApp</locationURI>
 </link>



As a result we have separate project "myApp" which is NOT depend on initial example project.
